# Match Data from Two Excel Files that Share Similar Attributes

Tags: attributes, extract, formula, offset, vlookup

I have two different Excel spreadsheets.  They have almost the same data, but it has been updated so some entries are not there anymore or some items have been added.

I feel that this shouldn't be too difficult, but I cannot figure it out.  I have attached a screenshot to help explain it.

I have some items that are labeled "I" or "O" for inside or outside in the "E" columns.  I need these in my new spreadsheet, and there are 300 or so of them.

**The values that are the same and need to match are KVA, LOW_VOLTAGE,COXX, and HIGH_VOLTAGE (rows A, B, C, and D).**

I would like to somehow have the formula look at these values from the original sheet, and if they are the same, it will put an "I" or "O" in the field "E" in my new sheet.

Thank you very much for helping me!

(I can't post an image yet, so I tried to break it down here.  Notice that only one row matches, so I would like that to update with "I".)

```
Original Sheet
A    B    C      D      E
1.5  120  99   7000     I
5    300  143  10000    O

NEW SHEET
A    B     C     D      E
1    100   87   500
1.5  120   99   7000
20   450   10   200
```

Answer (score 0):

*rows A, B, C, and D is confusing but perhaps concatenate values from the original sheet, in a helper column (say F) along the lines:

```
=A2&"|"&B2&"|"&C2&"|"&D2
```

copied down to suit and then in the new sheet something like:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&"|"&B2&"|"&C2&"|"&D2,Original!F:F,1,0)),"O","I")
```

copied down to suit.